# Custom InfoPath Form - Upload Image from Computer Dialog

Tags: custom-form, list-form

After customizing a sharepoint 2010 list form, I am losing the ability to upload an image from computer in a rich text box. It seems that this option is only available in the default SharePoint 2010 forms, and is removed when the form is customized.

Is there a way to add the add image from computer back to the form?

My goal is to create a form where users can embed images into the form, and then submit it to a SharePoint list.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

It looks like InfoPath (at least in 2007 version) is not supporting images in Rich text box control:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/insert-a-rich-text-box-HP010080917.aspx#BM3

Quote from `Compatibility considerations`:

> You can enable linked pictures for a rich text box in a
>   browser-compatible form template. However, embedded pictures are not
>   supported.

Alternative approach can be by using list item attachments or by using Infopath Attachment control.