# Insert images from computer into Rich Text Box

Tags: 2010, infopath, custom-form

I'm using SharePoint 2010.  Out of the box forms allow me to imbed images that I can upload from my computer. If I edit the form using InfoPath (something I want to do) I lose this ability.

Has anyone ran across this and if you have, is there a fix?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9777/custom-infopath-form-upload-image-from-computer-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation with no known workaround.  Sorry there isn't a better answer.